# Comparing every row in table on first sheet with a selected item on second sheet and display it in second sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have the following problem:

I have a file with two sheets. On the first sheet I have a table with some some facts. The important column is where the table contains the version of different application.

At the second sheet there I can select an project from a list and in a second cell there I can select previous versions of the selected project. Between the list with the versions and the list of my projects are a dependency which are on another sheet but that's not so important.

Now I get the problem. If I selected a previous version I want filtering my table on the first sheet with the selected version and every row which is less than the version should displayed at my second sheet.

Has Excel any formula which can solve my problem or have I to use `VBA`? I don't have any experience in `VBA`.

## Edit:

Okay, let's say my second sheet looks like this:

```
----------List with selected project -------- list of selected app-versions---------------
|
|
|
----------Headline A ------- Headline B --------- Headline C -------- Headline D ---------
```

If I have changed/selected an (old) version of my application there should be an event that is triggered.
The event should iterate through my first sheet which looks like:

```
----------Headline A ------- Headline B --------- Headline C --------- Headline D --------
|
|
|
----------cell A2 ---------- cell B2 ------------ cell C2 ------------ cell D2 --------
----------cell A3 ---------- cell B3 ------------ cell C3 ------------ cell D3 --------
----------cell A4 ---------- cell B4 ------------ cell C4 ------------ cell D4 --------
----------cell A5 ---------- cell B5 ------------ cell C5 ------------ cell D5 --------
```

In every iterated row it should compare the content of cell A2/3/4/5 with my selected project and the content of cell C2/3/4/5 with my selected app-version if the number of version is greater.

If both matches a passed specific cells should displayed at the columns in the second sheet.

I don't have MS Office on my Mac so I can't take any screenshots. I hope it's more clear what I wanted to do.

Comment: `worksheet_change` event in vba is most likely best way to go here, from what I understand of your question. I should also note, that I VTC because your question is very broad and somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0):

- Short answer:
  most likely, you need VBA.
- More detailed answer:

Your English is not 100% clear, so I do not understand whether you wish to "filter", as you wrote, which has the effect of hiding some rows in the first and second sheets, or all you need is simply to highlight and/or not show the content of some cells.

- if all you need is the latter, simple formulas plus some simple conditional formatting are enough (no VBA).
- but if, as it seems, you need to hide rows or to refresh 2 filters, then you need a handful of lines of VBA, most of which can be recorded as macro.

Pivot tables would not be enough because you want one operation (selecting a framework/version) to affect two worksheet.

Simple formulas would not be enough because filters do not update when the values of calculations change.

What you ask can be done in formulas (I did so in a project), but such formulas would be complex in order to show partial copies of both tables with their rows in a different order.
Also, you seem to ask how to filter the original tables, not how to show copies of the original tables.
In conclusion, the best solution in most cases, would be to learn how to write the few lines of VBA.

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it's getting more clearly. Sry for my english. It's not so good I know